# How can I do multi-boot with XOSL?

Tags: boot, multi-boot, operating-systems

I have seen someone using [XOSL](http://www2.arnes.si/~fkomar/xosl.org/) to do multi-boot. Actually, this is my first time messing up with multiple OS. Do you guys have any tutorials or guides for me to learn?

Assuming that I am using a brand new hard disk, what should I do first? If I have installed two or more OSs on the hard disk, how do I share files between these OSs?

A little bit off-topic: if my BIOS supports booting from a thumb drive, can it support booting from an external hard disk as well?

Comment: for everyone still looking for some answers to multibooting with XOSL and different operatingsystems like XP, Vista, Win7, Linux - this link might be of interest and give many valuable not too hard to understand informations: http://www.multibooters.co.uk/managers.html To encourage: I set up a multiboot laptop with complete independant microsoft OSs (xp pro,vista ultimate,win 7 ultimate, sharing the data on a separate partition) using xosl and it works great. ( Win7 was a bit of a task because I had to adjust the socalled BCD etc.) Well-it`s possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question i'd ask is, what OSes are you intending to install? If its linux and windows varients,Partion, then install windows first (oldest release to newest release) then install linux. Grub will take care of everything.

XOSL does seem to play nice with some of the oldies- which i'm unsure if grub supports.

Generally external hard drives *should* boot off usb *if* the firmware supports it. the only way to really tell is to try

Comment: Actually, I have 3 pcs in my house and none of them is mine (they are my parents'). Sometimes, it is quite inconvinient for me to use their pc. So, I plan to install Win7 on an external hard-disk and run on their pc. However, two of the pc is 32-bit and another is 64-bit. So, I have to install 2 versions of Win7 to run on all the pcs. Besides, I am also using Ubuntu.

Comment: 32 bit OSes run on 64 bit systems. As things go, it sounds like you might be better off running a single instance of windows 7 and using rdp to access it as things are.